# symfony2 default "deleted" field

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible in Symfony2 to set some sort of "default" deleted field? I have a deleted flag for all my entities and now I wonder if there is an easy way to exclude deleted entities (where deleted = 1) from all queries and magic methods.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best aproach that i know are using [soft-deletable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#softDeletable) from the Doctrine Behaviours, but is not magic. You must use a repository to retrieve the entities that are not deleted. You can override the findAll method with something similar like:

```
    public function findAll(){
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

      $qb->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('e.deletedAt'));

      return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I hope this can be util for you